# Why the kafka consumer is not listening to the first message?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In my test program,I start listener. Then sending messages in a loop.
If i send one message, it is not listning that message. If i send 2 messages, it listens one message.If I send 3 , it listens 2 messages..Why is that?

**Producer**

```
KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> message = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>(topic, serializedBytes);

if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("producing messages to topic : " + topic + "file : " + payload.get("name"));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    producer.send(message);
    System.out.println("producing ..");
}
```

**Consumer**

```
public void run() {

    try {
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> itr = m_stream.iterator();
        log.info("Kafka listener is ready to listen..");
        System.out.println("listens....");

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            byte[] data = itr.next().message();
            System.out.println("Message received : " + data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer properties**

```
enable.auto.commit=true

auto.commit.interval.ms=101

session.timeout.ms=7000

key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

zookeeper.connect=zk1.xx\:2181

heartbeat.interval.ms=1000

auto.offset.reset=smallest

serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder

bootstrap.servers=kk1.xx\:9092

group.id=test

consumer.timeout.ms=-1

fetch.min.bytes=1

receive.buffer.bytes=262144
```

Comment: How many partitions are you configuring in your kafka topic?

Comment: @jbarrueta  It is default topics..0 partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting following property in my producer.

```
request.required.acks=1
```